# No consigo que la función old de laravel 9 me rellene los inputs validados

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Estoy validando una serie de inputs de un formulario pero los campos que si cumplen la validación no los mantiene en el input cuando vuelve a la vista después de hacer la validación, por  aquí os dejo el código.

RegisterController

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'surnames' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'mail' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password_register' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8','confirmed'],
        'phone'=> ['required','regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/','min:9'],
        'location' => 'required|string',
        'latitude' => 'numeric',
        'longitude' => 'numeric'
    ]);
}
```

RegistersUsers

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $errors = $this->validator($request->all())->errors();
    
    if ($errors->any()) {
        return view('mobileApp.auth.register')->withErrors($errors);
    }

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    if ($response = $this->registered($request, $user)) {
        return $response;
    }

    return $request->wantsJson()
        ? new JsonResponse([], 201)
        : redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Vista del formulario

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="mb-2">
            <label for="name" class="form-label form-label-login">@lang('translation.Name')</label>
            <input id="name" type="text"
                    class="input form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name"
                    value="{{ old('name') }}"  autocomplete="name" autofocus>
            @error('name')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="mb-2">
            <label for="surnames" class="form-label form-label-login">@lang('translation.Surnames')</label>
            <input id="surnames" type="text"
                    class="input form-control @error('surnames') is-invalid @enderror" name="surnames"
                    value="{{ old('surnames') }}"  autocomplete="surnames">
            @error('surnames')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="mb-2">
            <label for="mail" class="form-label form-label-login">@lang('translation.Email')</label>
            <input id="mail" type="email"
                    class="input form-control @error('mail') is-invalid @enderror" name="mail"
                    value="{{ old('mail') }}"  autocomplete="mail">
            @error('mail')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="mb-2">
            <label for="phone" class="form-label form-label-login">@lang('translation.Phone')</label>
            <input id="phone" type="text"
                    class="input form-control @error('phone') is-invalid @enderror" name="phone"
                    value="{{ old('phone') }}" autocomplete="phone">
            @error('phone')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="mb-2">
            <label for="avatar" class="form-label form-label-login">@lang('translation.Photo')</label>
            <input id="avatar" type="file" accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg" 
                    class="input form-control" name="avatar"
                    autocomplete="avatar">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="mb-2">
            <label for="location" class="form-label form-label-login">@lang('translation.Location')</label>
            <label id="location-msg" class="form-label text-danger" >* @lang('translation.InsertValidLocation')</label>
            <input type="text" name="location" id="autocomplete" class="input form-control form-control--location @error('location') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('location') }}" >
            @error('location')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
            @enderror
            <input type="text" name="latitude" id="latitude" class="input form-control" value="{{ old('latitude') }}"  hidden >
            <input type="text" name="longitude" id="longitude" class="input form-control" value="{{ old('longitude') }}"  hidden >
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="mb-2">
            <label for="password" class="form-label form-label-login">@lang('translation.Password')</label>
            <input id="password" type="password"
                    class="input form-control @error('password_register') is-invalid @enderror" name="password_register"
                        autocomplete="new-password">
            @error('password_register')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="mb-2">
            <label for="password-confirm" class="form-label form-label-login">@lang('translation.ConfirmPassword')</label>
            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="input form-control"
                    name="password_confirmation"  autocomplete="new-password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 mb-2">
        <button type="submit" class="button button--big">@lang('translation.Register')</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Rutas a los controladores en AuthRouteMethod

```
// Registration Routes...
if ($options['register'] ?? true) {
    $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
}
```

La cuestión es que no se porque no recupera el dato correcto una vez esta validado no se si me falta algún detalle, todos mis campos se quedan en blanco aun que cumplan la validación, los errores los controlo bien y se muestran pero si solo tienes un campo mal todo el formulario se elimina y te salta el error del campo erróneo. Pero claro tienes que volver a escribir todo el form de nuevo y es una mala praxis.

Comment: Primero de todo gracias por tu respuesta, pero creo que no puedes ir asi por la vida, a caso sabes porque no he contestado o porque tardo en mirar los comentarios, ha sido fin de semana y el fin de semana no trabajo por lo tanto obviamente no  he entrado en stackoverflow para ver tu comentario, me parece que tienes que tener un poco  mas de respeto por los usuarios. Para terminar, eres el dueño de la plataforma?  Tranquilo.

Comment: Me parece  perfecto, pues con mas razón si ves que soy un usuario nuevo creo conveniente que me expliques lo que creas como lo acabas de hacer. Muchas gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'surnames' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'mail' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password_register' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
            'password_confirmation' => ['required','same:password_register'],
            'phone'=> ['required','regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/','min:9'],
            'location' => 'required|string',
            'latitude' => 'numeric',
            'longitude' => 'numeric'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            
            return redirect('register')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }
```

La solución esta en utilizar un **redirect()** o un  **redirect()->route()** además  de terminar la redirección con un **WithInput()** y no con un view()